# Функции для вычисления длины и площади окружности JS

Tags: javascript

Товарищи, доброго времени суток!

Есть задача:

> Пользователь вводит число R. Написать программу, которая выведет в
> консоль длину окружности и площадь круга с радиусом R.

Изначально для решения задачи я написала две функции следующего содержания:

```
const r = +prompt('Enter a number');

function circleLength(r) {
    let length = 2 * Math.PI * r;
    console.log(Math.round(length));
};

function circleSquare(r) {
    let square = Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 2);
    console.log(Math.round(square));
};

circleLength();
circleSquare();
```

Вывод в консоли (во всплывающем окне prompt введена цифра 4):

```
NaN
NaN
```

Знатно поругавшись, стала искать другие варианты решения задачи. Нашла следующее решение, оно выводит корректные значения:

```
const r = +prompt('Enter a number');

const circleLength = 2 * Math.PI * r;
console.log(Math.round(circleLength));

const circleSquare = Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 2);
console.log(Math.round(circleSquare));
```

Вывод в консоли (во всплывающем окне prompt введена цифра 4):

```
25
50
```

Я не понимаю, почему первый код не работает так, как второй. Ведь методы использованы одинаковые. Прошу помочь с выяснением причин. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: оффтоп: Площадь это Area, а не Square =)

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну почему же, если Трафальгарская, или Дворцовая, то вполне себе square 

Comment: @AlexeyTen А как же Red square - Красная площадь? %))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом коде вы не передаёте ничего на вход в функции. При этом там стоит переменная, которая должна быть каким-то значением. Если оно не передано, то оно по-умолчанию `undefined`. Дальше в математических операциях с `undefined` получается `NAN`.

Вот если бы там не было ожидание параметра (то есть было `function circleLength()` и `function circleSquare()`), то значение взялось из `r` верхнего скоупа.